# ntpd - can we disable TCP?

Tags: ntpd

When I run `ntpd`, I see that its binding to both `TCP` and `UDP` ports.

And in case of `TCP`, its picking some ephemeral ports, which are clashing with the ports that another process of mine is using!

I tried to look for config to disable `TCP`, but could not find any!, is there any way to force `ntpd` to only bind to `UDP/123`?

I have `ntpd` version `4.2.6p3`

--EDIT--

Sample output:

```
:~# netstat -pan | grep ntp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9101            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8050/ntpd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5756            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8050/ntpd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5757            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8050/ntpd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5758            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8050/ntpd
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to disable TCP here because NTP is a UDP based protocol and does not use TCP to communicate with the time server.

You can confirm this from the output of `netstat -apn | grep ntpd`

```
[root@server ~]# netstat -apn | grep ntpd
udp        0      0 <xx.xx.xx.xx>:123          0.0.0.0:*                20405/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123              0.0.0.0:*                20405/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                0.0.0.0:*                20405/ntpd
```

Comment: I added the output in the question. Of course, there are UDP ports as well (similar to what you pasted), I have shown only that part, where I see that its using the TCP ports.